# Envers: auto_increment (not PK) column not being audited

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I am implementing a JPA-EJB solution, which uses Hibernate-Envers to audit changes. Using MariaDB 5.5.49.

I have a table, which has an `auto_increment` field (this is not the PK, it is just another field), which I defined this way:

```
@NotNull
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(columnDefinition = "integer auto_increment")
private int caseNumber;
```

I also created an index and a unique constraint for this field as mysql requires.

Somehow Envers is not recognizing this field and doesn't store the value of caseNumber in the audition table. The `insert` sentence that is being logged saves all fields of my entity but this one.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is something wrong in the definition of the field? Is Envers not getting along with auto_increment?

Comment: Just off the top of my head I would guess that envers doesn't know that you are changing the column if it isn't mentioned in the insert statement. Perhaps a question for the Hibernate JIRA?

Comment: I guess you are right. I wanted to ask first here in order to know if someone faced this thing before... I will ask there and let you know what they have to say

Comment: Sounds good. It would be a good enhancement if they don't already have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the combination of both `@Generated` and `@Column`.

The default behavior of `@Column` is that the associated field/property is to be mapped as *insertable=true, updatable=true*.  When you combine `@Column` with `@Generated`, this changes the column annotation's behavior to be *insertable=false, updatable=false* since the intent is that the value will be maintained by the database.  This influenced the mapping Envers generated, thus the value for your `caseNumber` field simply was deemed not insertable nor updatable.

As mentioned in JIRA [HHH-10841](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10841), the fix was to simply detect this use case and make sure that the Envers mappings maintained a *insertable=true* state so that changes would be tracked and pushed to the column in the audit tables.